# Highchart heatmap: select all cells on click of button or checkbox

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, highcharts

I am using HighChart Heatmap. In that i want to select all the cells on click of "Click" button or check box.
I have created this [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/p7v2f117/20/)
I know this method

```
event.point.select(null,true);
```

But this works on click of each cell but i want to select all the cells without clicking on any cell.
1 more issue i am facing is that whenever i am calling the method

```
 chart.reflow()
```

my selection is going off for all the cells.
Please help me to solve this issue.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: If you set to true `enablePointSelect` in series setting, then selection should work on click at least as well. Problem with reflow/resize looks like a bug, so I reported the issue here: https://github.com/highcharts/highcharts/issues/5238

Comment: @KacperMadej Ok, Thanks..!! I did one work around, i am recreating the series and adding selected true or false in series and again calling the create chart function. Is there any other way to do this. please help me.

Comment: As another workaround you could update series after redraw to repaint wrongly colored points - http://jsfiddle.net/7bzoqzba/ (problematic points might blink). Maybe better workaround could be to change color of point on click and disable point selecting (it is disable by default options, so just do not enable it) - example: http://jsfiddle.net/zwo22je0/

Answer (score 2):

Well, I didn't find any direct method to select all features in one go. So i figure out alternative for this.

JSFiddle was quite useful to provide you the solution.

added this on click of external button:-

```
var currentFeature = chart.series[0].data[i];  
currentFeature.select(null,true);
```

[Click here to see this in JSFiddle...](http://jsfiddle.net/vikash2402/p7v2f117/21/)

***Hoping this will help you :)***